# Shopify Webhooks for Bulk Product Update

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I set up a development shop on Shopify to test webhooks. I'm using this for proof of concept to update an external system whenever a product changes within Shopify. All seemed to be working as intended until I tried using the bulk product edit feature(the tool, not the csv import). I'm not receiving any webhook posts on bulk update. 
    I have several webhooks set up for various triggers, and they are all seemingly working. The product/update webhook works if I edit the product or its inventory individually, but not if I use the bulk edit tool.
    I actually had 2 separate product/update webhooks going to 2 separate URLs, but I removed one of them just to be sure that wasn't causing any conflicts. I also tried chat support on Shopify, but they actually referred me here.
    I really need for this to work as I'm not being given enough time to develop an API app to accomplish this.

Comment: Maybe Shopify does not fire off a webhook when the merchant uses the bulk update tool. That would kinda make some sense, since they also don't fire off webhooks on the bulk import of products either.

Comment: That's kind of what I'm afraid of. I've seen several posts from users saying they were getting flooded by webhooks after someone imported product changes, so I'm wondering if Shopify disabled that. If so, they probably didn't ever have it on the bulk edit tool. I'm just hoping that Shopify will see this and respond.

Comment: I would not hold my breath. The last time Shopify responded here was years ago. Trust your experiments and move on. You know the answer already.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this up! Those webhooks should now fire consistently when using the bulk editor.